# How to reduce the number of update queries hibernate makes to a cascaded table?

Tags: sql, performance, hibernate

I'm trying to improve the update performance of an application using Hibernate 4.3.

I have a list of people and towns, like so

```
@Table(name = "PERSON", schema = "COUNTY", catalog = "")
@Entity
public class PersonBean{

  @MapsId("town")
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "TOWN_ID")
  private Long townID;

  @Column(name = "NAME")
  @Basic
  private String personName;

  @Column(name = "UPDATE_DATE")
  @Basic
  private Date updateDate;

  ...
}
```

...

```
@Table(name = "TOWNS", schema = "COUNTY")
@Entity
public class TownBean {

    @Column(name = "ID")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "town_id_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "town_id_gen", sequenceName = "TOWN_SEQ")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    @Basic
    private String name;

... (more simple properties) ...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "people", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @BatchSize(size = 50)
    private List<PersonBean> people;
```

When the  update of these items is done simply by calling

```
repository.saveAndFlush(town);
```

Some of these towns are pretty big, 20,000 people in a town is not unusual.

In the DAO and resource, all updates occur at a town level... so for example, to change the name of one person in the town, you would PUT a new town resource with the complete new list of names. 
In the database, this requires the update of all the person rows referencing that town to change the updateDate, and Hibernate does this by issuing one update query for each person, which can mean 20,000 queries. (The @BatchSize annotation [applies only to reading](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#annotations-hibernate-batchsize), sadly.) This kills system performance.

I think I can optimize this by replacing the `repository.saveAndFlush(town)` operation with a custom transaction logic that opens a transaction, flushes the list of people in groups using batching, and then writes the town object...

Is there a smarter way I can reduce the number of update queries Hibernate sends (by batching or otherwise) without changing the system behavior? Maybe there's some cleverer way using [custom SQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-custom-crud-example), [Named Entity Graphs](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity/) or something else?

Comment: Seems like a bad model to put the `updateDate` on the child table. Why not just store it at the town level?

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree.. and I'm hoping that it will happen, but that involves refactoring another system that's outside my control

Comment: Batched updates? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch-jdbcbatch

Comment: Sounds great - but I'm on hibernate 4.3, I can't set the batch size for just this session

Comment: This is available in 4.3: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch15.html What's wrong with setting it globally?

Comment: I tried it, but it does nothing... as I understand, that's because it only affects updates that apply to collections of towns, not collections of people >> http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-fetching-strategies-examples/